# How to paginate in a Catalyst app using elasticsearch?

Tags: perl, elasticsearch, pagination, catalyst

I am using the web framework Catalyst and I want to paginate results from elasticsearch query with the plugin [Data::Paginator](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Paginator). Here is my code for now:

> Root.pm

```
sub search :Global {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;
    my $search = $c->model('Search');
    my $m = $c->req->params->{m};

    my $from = 0;
    my $size = 10;          

    my $results = $search->search(
      index => 'index1',
      type => 'type1',
      body  => {
        query => {
            prefix => { entree => $m }
        },
    from => $from,
    size => $size
      }
    );

    my $pager = Data::Paginator->new(
     current_page => 1,
     entries_per_page => 10,
     total_entries => $results->{hits}{total},
    );
    my $p = { next_page=>$pager->next_page, previous_page=>$pager->previous_page };

    my @res=();
    for my $i ( @{ $results->{hits}->{hits} } ) {
      my $h = { entree => $i->{_source}->{entree}, contenu => $i->{_source}->{contenu} };
      push @res, $h;
    }

    $c->stash(template => 'search.tt', total => $results->{hits}{total}, m=>$m , res=>\@res, pager=>$p);
    $c->forward('View::HTML');
}
```

And there is the template

> search.tt

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Résultats</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>[% total %] résultat(s) pour [% m %]</h1>
    [% IF total >0 %]
      [% FOREACH h IN res %]
        <h2>[% h.entree %]</h2>
        <p>[% h.contenu %]</p>
      [% END %]
    [% ELSE %]
      <p>Pas de résultat</p>
    [% END %]
  </body>
  <footer>
    <a href="/">Nouvelle recherche</a>
    <a href="/search?offset=[% pager.previous_page %]&m=[% m %]">Previous Page</a>
    <a href="/search?offset=[% pager.next_page %]&m=[% m %]">Next Page</a>
    <a> DATA PAGINATOR TEST [% pager %]</a>
 </footer>
</html>
```

I would like to make a new query through elasticsearch when I click "Next Page" or "Previous Page" and display the new results:

```
 my $results = $search->search(
      index => 'index1',
      type => 'type1',
      body  => {
        query => {
            prefix => { entree => $m }
        },
    from => $from + 10,
```

> OR from => $from -10,

```
    size => $size
      }
    );
```

Some hints on how to do that would be nice, thanks.

***EDIT 1:***

> Root_v2.pm

```
sub search :Global {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;
    my $search = $c->model('Search');
    my $m = $c->req->params->{m};
    my $offset = $c->req->params->{offset} ? $c->req->params->{offset} : 0;

    my $from = 0;
    my $size = 10;          

    my $results = $search->search(
      index => 'index1',
      type => 'type1',
      body  => {
        query => {
            prefix => { entree => $m }
        },
    from => $offset*$size,
    size => $size
      }
    );

    my $pager = Data::Paginator->new(
     current_page => $offset,
     entries_per_page => 10,
     total_entries => $results->{hits}{total},
    );
    my $p = { next_page=>$pager->next_page, previous_page=>$pager->previous_page };

    my @res=();
    for my $i ( @{ $results->{hits}->{hits} } ) {
      my $h = { entree => $i->{_source}->{entree}, contenu => $i->{_source}->{contenu} };
      push @res, $h;
    }

    $c->stash(template => 'search.tt', total => $results->{hits}{total}, m=>$m , res=>\@res, pager=>$p);
    $c->forward('View::HTML');
}
```

I get the offset from the href in my search.tt file and I used it to modify my "from" parameter in the elasticsearch query.

But I have a problem with the "current_page" from Data::Paginator : it's never equal to 0 even when my $offset is equal to 0 itself (see current_page => $offset). I miss the 10th to 20th results when I first click on next page.

The behaviour is like this:

> Click on search button: OFFSET=0 / CURRENT_PAGE=1 / NEXT_PAGE=2
>   / PREVIOUS_PAGE=not def
>
> Click on next page button: OFFSET=2 / CURRENT_PAGE=2 / NEXT_PAGE=3
>   / PREVIOUS_PAGE=1
>
> Click on previous page button: OFFSET=1 / CURRENT_PAGE=1 / NEXT_PAGE=2
>   / PREVIOUS_PAGE=not def

You can see that I miss results when I first click on next page button, due to my offset directly goes from 0 to 2 skipping 1.

***EDIT 2***

> Root_v3.pm

Modifications:

```
my $offset = $c->req->params->{offset} ? $c->req->params->{offset} : O; 
▼▼▼
my $offset = $c->req->params->{offset} ? $c->req->params->{offset} : 1;
```

AND

```
from => $offset*$size,
▼▼▼
from => ($offset-1)*$size,
```

Now it works !

Comment: Do you want this to be a page reload or an AJAX call?

Comment: See my Edit 1. I dont want to make AJAX call.

Comment: I think you should try to read up more about pagination.

Comment: Some documentations in mind ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the original post with the two edits I made.